# how to download folder containing files(pdf,png etc) from php server in android

Tags: java, android

i want to download folder containing files like pdf,jpg,png etc from web services.I have written a application that can download pdf,png file.But i want to download folder containing several files. So my question is- is it possible to download folder and if yes then  how can i download folder from server in android. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can download one file, why wouldn't you be able to download several? Create the folder on Android, queue the files and start the next download when the current is finished, filling the folder. Also Android supports [ZIP](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/package-summary.html), so that might be your best call.

Comment: I guess you cannot zip file on a server if you are accessing those files through an http interface (which I guess is the case).

Comment: PHP has ZIP support so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Then in that case the web service itself needs to be changed. Which will involve zipping the folder and then the client will need to download just one zip file. (But I am not sure if the web services is written in PHP)

Answer (score 0):

Folder is nothing but an FILE but a different type of file. Once you get the folder you can list down the files in it. You already have URL with the folder, u just need to append the URL of the folder to the files in it and download them one by one.